# "E: Unable to locate package touchpad-indicator" even after adding repository and enabling sources

Tags: 12.04, indicator, touchpad

I'm trying to install the touchpad-indicator discussed here:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/touchpad-indicator-now-automatically.html

but I keep getting this error, even after using Software Center to enable those software sources. Any help? I'd like to have this program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install touchpad-indicator by [downloading](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/atareao_atareao/precise/main/base/touchpad-indicator) the .deb file.  Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder where the file was downloaded, and run the command below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>
```

Now keep in mind if you get the error below:

```
touchpad-indicator depends on gir1.2-gconf-2.0; however:
  Package gir1.2-gconf-2.0 is not installed.
touchpad-indicator depends on python-pyudev; however:
  Package python-pyudev is not installed.
```

You can download Package gir1.2-gconf-2.0 [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/gnome_3/oneiric/main/base/gir1.2-gconf-2.0), and Package python-pyudev [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/i386/python-pyudev)